# Geoserver - Disallowing unauthenticated user from using getLegendGraphic Service

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I created a geoserver rule as `ADMIN and *.*` for allowing an authenticated admin to see all services and functions.  Why does Geoserver allow Geoexplorer to retrieve the legend images for saved maps even if I haven't authenticated yet?  Is this not how service rules work?  Is this a bug? I was looking through the Geoserver JIRA and could not find any mention of this.  My current authentication chain does not allow for anonymous authentication.

I'm using Geoserver 2.5.1 as a WAR with Tomcat7.

Simple request params

`http://domain.com/geoserver/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&width=20&height=20&layer=layer&transparent=true&format=image%2Fpng&legend_options=fontAntiAliasing%3Atrue%3BfontSize%3A11%3BfontName%3AArial&SCALE=2179976.903424944`